# Error description : Cannot return to provided redirect_uri

Tags: java, android, api, stack

I'm trying to create an application in which one of the features would be to add user login/logout .

I'm following this : https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication

So i have a button in my activity, Clicking on that button it redirects you to the browser for logging into stack overflow website. I would like to return to my app once the user logs in . but it says '**Cannot return to provided redirect_uri**'

Here its my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vivek.stack.client">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".retro.Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="aahost"
                    android:scheme="bbscheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Mine">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

My Login class :

```
package com.vivek.stack.client.retro;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.vivek.stack.client.R;

/**
 * Created by Shiva on 14-04-2016.
 */
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {


    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.snack);

        Button loginButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String uri = "https://stackexchange.com/oauth?\n" +
                        "scope=private_info&\n" +
                        "redirect_uri=bbscheme://aahost&\n"+
                        "client_id=" ;

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,

                        Uri.parse(uri));
                if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // the intent filter defined in AndroidManifest will handle the return from ACTION_VIEW intent
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(redirectUri)) {
            // use the parameter your API exposes for the code (mostly it's "code")
            String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
            if (code != null) {
                // get access token
                Log.i("MYCODECODE" , code);

                Snackbar.make(relativeLayout ,code , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (uri.getQueryParameter("error") != null) {
                // show an error message here
                Log.i("NO CODE" , "NO CODE");
                Snackbar.make(relativeLayout ,"we did not get" , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }


}
```

It should return to the app once the login is successful.

Comment: I hope I could get some help. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Solution is just make sure, Your `android:host` and `android:scheme`matches your `redirect_uri` which you gave while registering your application.